# string input error while inserting data c# (INPUT STRING WAS NOT CORRECTLY FORMATTED ERROR)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaoSa.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb0E7.png)i am facing a problem , i have posted the stored procedure,the c# code and the error that is occurring while inserting the data into the database. I need a solution of it

```
 string dataString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-E5V2JHG;Initial catalog=hospital_management;Integrated Security=SSPI";
          SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(dataString);


          connect.Open();



          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Add_doctor", connect);
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

          cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactNo", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox3.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@GenderId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedText);
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@Nationality", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox5.Text;
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@salary", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text);
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = dateTimePicker1;
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@shiftId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox3.SelectedText);
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@qualification", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox9.Text;
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox10.Text;
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@HireDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = dateTimePicker2;
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pass", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox8.Text;
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@Religion", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox6.Text;
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@specId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedText);

          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          MessageBox.Show("Command Executed");
          connect.Close();
```

this is in c#

```
Create Proc AddDoctor
@EMPtypeID VARCHAR(50),
@FirstName VARCHAR(50),
@LastName VARCHAR(50),
@ContactNo INT,
@EmailId VARCHAR(50),
@GenderId INT,
@Nationality VARCHAR(50),
@salary INT,
@DOB DATETIME2,
@shiftID INT,
@qualification VARCHAR(50),
@Address VARCHAR(50),
@HireDate DATETIME2,
@Pass VARCHAR(50),    
@Religion VARCHAR(50),
@specId INT
AS
BeGIN


insert into EMPLOYEES (_EMPtypeID,_FirstName,_LastName,_ContactNo,_EmailId,
_GenderId,_Nationality,_salary,_DOB,_ShiftId,_qualification,
_Address,_HireDate,_Password,_Religion,_specialityId)

values (@EMPtypeID,@FirstName,@LastName,@ContactNo,@EmailId, 
@GenderId,@Nationality,@salary,@DOB,@shiftID,@qualification,
@Address,@HireDate,@Pass,@Religion,@specId);

END
```

this is the stored procedure in the database

[image: this error occurs]

Comment: But where is the error?

Comment: Do you perhaps need to do ALTER, instead of CREATE? Posting a picture of your code with a word underlined doesn't really point to a concrete problem.

Comment: The string for HireDate or DOB is probably in a format that SQL doesn't recognise

Comment: then what should be its correct data type ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `DOB` and `HireDate` is the problem.
Change this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = dateTimePicker1;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@HireDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = dateTimePicker2;
```

To this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@HireDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = dateTimePicker2.Text.ToString();
```

Because there is no input receiving in that 2 table, like an abstract figure of the date. So you need to make it a concrete string. Good for you SQL Server can accept the `date` in `string` format if it is in `yyyy-mm-dd`